# Reminders: Move list item to other list

Tags: macos, reminders

is it possible to move a reminder from one reminders list to another?

For example I have two lists:

1. Today
2. Tomorrow

How could I move for example "call cindy" from "Tomorrow" to "Today"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the entry, right click, go to the "Move to List" menu entry, select the destination list you want.  (Or drag and drop.)

When I first tried this the difficult part was selecting the item rather than editing it...I needed to be sure to click white space off to the right of the title.

Comment: Great answer, I guess this isn't possible on iOS?

Comment: Sort of....  Tap a reminder and it brings up a dialog with a "Show More..." item.  Tap that and you can choose a list for that reminder.  (I'm on an iPad...don't know if it's similar for smaller devices.)

Comment: @PhillipMills I can confirm that it's the same on my iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

I foolishly tried dragging and dropping 5 items from one iCloud account to another.

Both lists bear the same title as shown in the Reminders app. Maybe that's why 4 items were deleted instead of moved.

Any way to restore the lost items from a Time Machine backup? I can't seem to find a .plist for Reminders in my Library.

Answer (score -1):

The app should automatically transfer items from the 'Tomorrow' list to the 'Today' list at midnight.

It seems bogus that it doesn't.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Please don't add comments in the _Answer_ field as this is for answers to questions. Once you have enough [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you can add a comment on the question/answer you wanted to comment on. Alternatively, you can offer a new answer instead that you feel is a better solution. See [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for tips on providing answers here.